# How to check if any cell in a row is 0 with PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

The title says it all.

I want to say `"SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = 1"` and if any cell besides `id`, is `0` I want to do something.

Comment: `where id=1 and 0 in (list,of,fields,you,want,to,test)`?

Comment: @MarcB Answer it, that is the solution actually

Comment: @MarcB are there no way to avoid writing all the rest of the fields?

Comment: @Legarndary If your problem is you don't want to type out all the fields (or you want the code to work even if you change the table) you can check through the fields in a foreach loop in PHP.

Comment: @dragmosh an example would be much appreciated